# error in running cpanm --installdeps on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dbd, cpanm

I'm trying to intall defects4j on ubuntu 18.04. but when I run the command:cpanm --installdeps .
I get errors on jason and DBD.

```
faeze@ubuntu:~/defects4j$ cpanm --installdeps .
```

```
--> Working on .
Configuring /home/faeze/defects4j ... OK
==> Found dependencies: JSON::Parse, DBD::CSV
--> Working on JSON::Parse
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/B/BK/BKB/JSON-Parse-0.62.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring JSON-Parse-0.62 ... OK
Building and testing JSON-Parse-0.62 ... FAIL
! Installing JSON::Parse failed. See /home/faeze/.cpanm/work/1689173283.7212/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Finding DBD::CSV on cpanmetadb failed.
! Permission denied opening uncompressed index for write
! Couldn't find module or a distribution DBD::CSV (0.48)
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'JSON::Parse' is not installed, Module 'DBD::CSV' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for ..
```

I installed jason and mysql, try running with root access, installed relevant libraries in cpanm, and updated all packages. but the error doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It was due to `cpanmetadb`. So, I reinstalled `cpan` and its modules, and updated my packages and sudo itself. I do some of them with root access. Then I download and install `JSON::Parse` separately. After all these are done, I run the command `cpanm --installdeps .` and it worked.